# Writeable active inline response in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, mailitem

I have the following code from some blog that inserts HTML from the clipboard into an outlook email.

```
Sub PrependClipboardHTML()
Dim email As Outlook.MailItem
Dim cBoard As DataObject

Set email = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
Set cBoard = New DataObject


cBoard.GetFromClipboard
email.HTMLBody = cBoard.GetText + email.HTMLBody

Set cBoard = Nothing
Set email = Nothing

End Sub
```

It works great except that the email has be in its own window (i.e. popped-out) otherwise it will fail.

I was looking around on the documentation and found `Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/explorer-activeinlineresponse-property-outlook).

However the documentations says that it is read-only, and indeed it does not work. Is there way to get a writable version of the inline response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It works great except that the email has be in its own window (i.e. popped-out) otherwise it will fail.

That is because you have the following statement in the code:

```
Set email = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```

> However the documentations says that it is read-only, and indeed it does not work.

Try to use the following code instead:

```
Set email = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse
```

The [ActiveInlineResponse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/explorer-activeinlineresponse-property-outlook) property is read-only, but not the object's properties you are going to use. That means you can't set another mail item to the inline response, but will be able to set up properties of the retrieved item.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I should have been clearer, but I have tried it with `Set email = Application.ActiveExplorer.ActiveInlineResponse` and it does nothing. That is what I meant it does not work.

Comment: You can get the `EntryID` value and try to get a new instance of the item by calling `NameSpace.GetItemFromID` where you can set the body. Or just display it in a new inspector window by calling the `Display` method.

Comment: I was mistaken. I had something else in my code that made the `ActiveInlineRespose` not work. It works as you you said it would.

Comment: Great news! Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 1):

*Maybe you're trying to work with [ActiveExplorer + Selection.Item Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-activeexplorer-method-outlook)*

*Example*

> ```
> Option Explicit
> Public Sub Example()    
>     Dim email  As Outlook.MailItem
>     Set email = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
>         Debug.Print email.Subject ' print on immediate window    
> End Sub
> ```

*[Or Work with both opened and selected items](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/outlook-vba-work-with-open-item-or-select-item/)*

> ```
> Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
>     Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
>
>     Set objApp = Application
>
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
>         Case "Explorer"
>             Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
>         Case "Inspector"
>             Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
>     End Select
>
>     Set objApp = Nothing
> End Function
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate two HTML strings and expect a valid HTML back. The two must be merged.

That being said, use Word Object Model to paste from the clipboard:

```
Application.ActiveEXplorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor.Application.Selection.Paste()
```

Comment: How do I "merge" two HTML strings?

Comment: Take everything between the `<body>` and `</body>` tags in the first HTML string, insert it immediately after the `<body>` tag in the second HTML string. You will then need to copy the styles from the headers, etc. Not easy. Let somebody else do the job - do use `Selection.Paste` in the Word Object Model.